# Debug nested loop in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I have some nested loop and want to stop at N iteration .Suppose I want to stop at i = 7 and j =10.
I use the conditional breakpoints and enter this condition  " i == 7 && j ==10 " in condition expression box.But the program does not stop at i = 7 and j =10.It is running to finish.How to fix this?

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
  for(int j=0 ;j<=20;j++)
  {
    printf("i=%d  j=%d",i,j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not braking loop because it is nested loop you have to use a flag element to the break the loop. in this case a  is the flag element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int a = 0;

    for(i=0;i<=10 ;i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ;j<=20;j++)
        {
            printf("i=%d  j=%d\n",i,j);

            if(j==10)
                if(i==7)
                {
                    a=1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    
        if(a)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```